# CakePHP undefined index error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to access the email address for a user that's signed in and I can do so successfully in all of my Controllers except for one.

Here is the error I'm getting

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 37]
```

And here is the corresponding line of code (remember, this works in all of my other controllers).

```
<center><font color="black"><td><?php echo $user['User']['email']; ?></td></text></center>
```

Here is the DemosController

```
<?php
// app/Controller/DemosController.php
class DemosController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add','logout');

        $user = $this->Demo->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));  //this throws the error
        //$user = $this->Demo->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));  //Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in
        $this->set('user', $user);

    }

    //display the knockout table
    public function index($article = null) {

    }


}
```

I do not need a table in the database for this Controller. It's simply to display a table for demo purposes. Can I just let it reference user?

```
class Demo extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';         
}
```

Why can I access this in all of my controllers except this one? Is the Model/table situation causing the error? If so, is there a way to disable the use of a table?

Comment: have you try to rename your controller to respect the CakePHP convention like that DemosController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting properties of the logged-in user via AuthComponent

You **don't** have to pass information of the currently logged-in user to the view via a 'viewVar'.
To access properties of the currently logged-in user outside of the controller, use the 'static' interface of the `AuthComponent`

Inside your views or layouts, output the information like this;

```
<p>The current users email is: <?php echo AuthComponent::user('email') ?></p>
<p>The current users id is: <?php echo AuthComponent::user('id') ?></p>
<p>And all properties of the user are:</p>
<pre><?php print_r(AuthComponent::user());?></pre>
```

See: [**Accessing the logged in user**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)

You can **remove** these lines from your `beforeFilter()`;

```
$user = $this->Demo->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));  //this throws the error
//$user = $this->Demo->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));  //Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in
$this->set('user', $user);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems going here:

First, when not using a table, you set a model's `$useTable` property to false.
Secondly, without a table, no database call will work (just plug in sample data to the table anyway, who would know if its a demo?)

It still bears mentioning that `$this->Model->read()` is for updating records. Changing the line to the following will allow the set call to function properly:

```
$this->Demo->find('first', array(
     'conditions' => array(
          'Demo.field' => $this->Auth->user('id')
 )));
```

Comment: Thanks, I set useTable to false for now. However, it appears as if it's trying to access the blog database (made it from the tutorial in the cookbook). Here is the error it's giving "SQL Query: SELECT FROM `blog`.`demos` AS `Demo` WHERE `Demo`.`field` = '12' LIMIT 1"

Comment: This is probably a separate issue, I'd be happy to address it in another question. I'm going to need your models and relationships though, as Cake usually uses the AS statement when aliases are involved.

Comment: Not all of it (i.e. the  functions) just the headers with the relationship data