# How can I see what user is currently logged into my system?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm using CakePHP 2.3 and here's my `AppController.php` and `UsersController.php` files, pieces that are relevant to user log in:

```
class AppController extends Controller {


public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

   public $components = array(
      'RequestHandler',
      'Session',
      'Auth' => array(
          'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dpts', 'action' => 'index'),
          'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
      )
  );

  public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->UserAuth->beforeFilter($this); // Error fires here.
    $authUser = $this->UserAuth->getUser();
    $this->set('loggedInUser', $authUser);
  }

}

=================================================================================

<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {            
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'pages'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Correo y/o contraseña incorrecta.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the object of the user currently logged in?

I'm getting an error in the beforeFilter() of the AppController:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function beforeFilter() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testapp\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to get current user logged in information.

```
   function beforeFilter(){     
        $first_name = $this->Auth->user('first_name');
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->set('first_name', $first_name);
    }
```

Add code in AppController.php

Comment: Say I want to show a property in `$authUser` in a nav section in the `Layouts/default.ctp` file, where would I put this call if I want `$authUser` to be accesible in the layout file? I want to say something like "Welcome back, <?php echo $authUser['first_name']; ?>"

Comment: use beforeFilter() function for that and put it in Appcontroller.php  like below 
  function beforeFilter(){
 
   $this->UserAuth->beforeFilter($this);
   $authUser = $this->UserAuth->getUser();
   $this->set('authUser', $authUser); }

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function beforeFilter() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testapp\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 50` - I've edited my question with the code as it looks.

Comment: Check my modified answer..

Comment: @Serg it's better to use the 'static' interface of the `AuthComponent`. I described this in another question here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096176/cakephp-undefined-index-error/16098675#16098675